# Delphi Getting control origin regarding form's left

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to get the Left,Top coordinates of a control regarding to the container form. The target control may be, at the same time, inside of any number of other containers such as TPanels and TGroupBoxes. That means that to get the target control origin, the code should have to take into account the Left,Top coordinates of all the other containers + the Left,Top coordinates of the target control itself. Instead, I'm using a second approuch, wich consist in using the ClientToScreen function to get the Left,Top screen coordinates of the target control and after that, subtracting the Left,Top coordinates of the form. Saddly this approach is not working. I'm attaching an image that clarifies my thinkings and has the actual code I used to calculate the desired coordinates. I appreciate any help on this.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [ClientToParent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.ClientToParent) and specify form as `Parent` parameter.

You have to pass coords relative to control, so Top, Left of the control will be at control's (0,0)

```
Control.ClientToParent(TPoint.Create(0,0), Form)
```

Comment: I coded `targetOrigin := ClientToParent (Point (fTarget.Left, fTarget.Top), fMainForm);`, where `targetOrigin` is a TPoint. That's OK?

Comment: @VitalyG. Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly! What made the difference was the 0,0 coordinates. I didn't figured out that detail. In my mind, I had to pass the target's Left,Top coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

@VitaliyG's answer shows how to convert the coordinates of the control's absolute top-left corner to Form-relative client coordinates.  If you want to convert the coordinates of the top-left corner of the control's client area instead, you can pass the control's `ClientOrigin` property to the Form's `ScreenToClient()` method:

```
function GetControlClienOrigin(const aControl: TControl: const aForm: TForm): TPoint;
begin
  Result := aForm.ScreenToClient(aControl.ClientOrigin);
end;
```

If the control in question is a `TWinControl` descendant, an alternative is to use the Win32 API [`MapWindowPoints()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145046.aspx) function instead:

```
function GetControlClientOrigin(const aControl: TWinControl: const aForm: TForm): TPoint;
var
  Pt: TPoint;
begin
  Pt := Point(0, 0);
  SetLastError(0);
  if MapWindowPoints(aControl.Handle, aForm.Handle, Pt, 1) = 0 then
    CheckOSError(GetLastError);
  Result := Pt;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

So these 3 statements return the same, wanted `TPoint`:

```pascal
aControl.ClientOrigin - aForm.ClientOrigin;
```

```pascal
aControl.ClientToParent(Point(0,0), aForm);
```

```pascal
aForm.ScreenToClient(aControl.ClientOrigin);
```